# Why my SysLink control appears as plain text?

Tags: c++, url, winapi, text, createwindow

I'm trying to add a clickable URL on my window. I'm using the Win32 API, C++, and Visual Studio.

When I try the example from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-syslink-controls#instructions), the link appears as plain text, with the `<a>` tags.

They put the Hyperlink in the title bar, but they use `WS_CHILD`, which hides it. So I used `WS_CAPTION` to show it.

What am I missing? Is it supposed to work only in dialogs?

[image: screenshot behavior]

Here are the related code parts:

`wWinMain()`:

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
icex.dwICC = ICC_LINK_CLASS;
InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
```

`MyRegisterClass2()`:

```
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc2;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = NULL;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName = WC_LINK;
wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
```

`InitInstance()`:

```
hWndMain = CreateWindowW(
    szWindowClass, 
    szTitle, 
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
    xPos,
    yPos,
    windowWidth,
    windowHeight,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    hInstance,
    nullptr
);
```

```
RECT rectLink = {
    30,
    30,
    300,
    40
};
hWndLink = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    WC_LINK,
    L"link: <A HREF=\"https://www.google.com\">click</A>",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CAPTION,
    rectLink.left,
    rectLink.top,
    rectLink.right,
    rectLink.bottom,
    hWndMain,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);
if (!hWndLink)
{
    return FALSE;
}
ShowWindow(hWndMain, nCmdShow);
ShowWindow(hWndLink, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWndMain);
UpdateWindow(hWndLink);
```

`WndProc2()`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: according to the downvote i would be missing something big, that's not as indicating as a comment but thanks anyway

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you should post the code you tried, in the question itself. By the way, the question has a close vote for *'needs debugging details.'*

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i just posted the related code parts

Comment: btw i tried to replace the "text" tag by "plaintext" but it's not updating apparently, i think i did put plaintext at first also... weird ^^

Comment: @Raphael What you have shown is not a [mcve] that can be copy/pasted and compiled as-is. In any case, you should not be re-registering a custom `WndProc` for the `WC_LINK` class, it is already pre-registered by the OS.  Simply create the SysLink control as a child of your main window using the pre-existing `WC_LINK` class. And get rid of the `WS_CAPTION` style on the SysLink, that doesn't belong there.  And you don't need to call `ShowWindow()` and `UpdateWindow()` on the SysLink, either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the help. I will learn about minimal reproducible examples. What do you mean by "using the pre-existing WC_LINK class"? I shouldn't call `RegisterClassExW()` for this child?

Comment: I'm a beginner so it's very probable that I missed something that is totally obvious for you.

Comment: I didn't know that SysLink controls are not compatible with Windows XP SP2, so I will go try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35711995/22157294). I'm still interested to know what I did wrong there.

Comment: XP? Are you serious? Microsoft has already dropped support for Windows 7 and 8 (and so have most other software vendors). If memory serves, support for XP was dropped something like 10 years ago or so...

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes I'm doing this coding to make some stuff for an old multiplayer game (the first Call of Duty from 2003). I don't want my tools to require dependencies that the original game doesn't need, since these tools are intended to be shared to the players. Players are on the first patch now (1.1), if you get the game from Steam you would have to downgrade it, come take a look at www.cod.pm sometimes if you are curious, we mostly play the same map since 20 years so it's kinda badass how some players are skilled

Comment: @JerryCoffin We are mostly playing during the evening* (EU time)

Comment: @Raphael: Well, I guess in a way that kind of makes sense, anyway...

Comment: @JerryCoffin I was just having the same issue using the Static Control alternative for my url, what fixed my SysLink control issue in your answer just fixed the Static one, it seems I don't know how the "cycle" works actually.

Comment: @Raphael: yeah, knowing what to do where/when is a big part of Windows programming--and yes it's often not obvious at all why you have to do things at particular times (though you can usually figure out, if you try hard enough).

Comment: @Raphael "*I shouldn't call RegisterClassExW() for this child?*" - no. Only register your own classes that need custom configs/WndProcs (like your main window). Do not register system-provided classes, they are already registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to be sure what you have wrong.

The main steps you need to get a functioning SysLink control are:

1. Add support for Common Controls 6 to the manifest. I usually do this with a pragma:

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

You didn't mention anything about doing this, but without it, `InitCommonControlsEx` will fail, and the control won't be created or displayed at all (at least on older versions of Windows--I guess I've never tested what happens if you skip that on a recent version).

2. Call `InitCommonControlsEx`, usually right in `WinMain`, before creating your main window:

```cpp
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ex{};
    ex.dwSize = sizeof(ex);
    ex.dwICC = ICC_LINK_CLASS;
    if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&ex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"InitCommonControlsEx", L"Registration failed", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
```

3. In your main Window's `WndProc`, create the SysLink:

```cpp
    case WM_CREATE:
        link = CreateWindow(
            WC_LINK,
            L"<a href=\"www.google.com\">Google</a>",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LWS_USEVISUALSTYLE,
            10, 10, 400, 20,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            0);
        break;
```

4. To actually make use of the control, add a WM_NOTIFY handler as well, something along this really general order:

```cpp
    case WM_NOTIFY: {
        NMHDR *nmh = (NMHDR*)lParam;
        switch (nmh->code) {
        case NM_CLICK:
            if (nmh->hwndFrom == link) {
                NMLINK* lnkHdr = (NMLINK*)lParam;
                MessageBox(NULL, lnkHdr->item.szUrl, L"Here we open", MB_OK);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

4. Link with `ComCtl32.lib`

Here's a quick demo program that puts all of the above together. The skeleton is just what Visual Studio generates for an empty Windows program, with the above bits added in appropriate places.

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#include "framework.h"
#include "SysLink2.h"
#include <CommCtrl.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND link;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX ex{};
    ex.dwSize = sizeof(ex);
    ex.dwICC = ICC_LINK_CLASS | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&ex)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"InitCommonControlsEx", L"Registration failed", MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_SYSLINK2, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SYSLINK2));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SYSLINK2));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_SYSLINK2);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        link = CreateWindow(
            WC_LINK,
            L"<a href=\"www.google.com\">Google</a>",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LWS_USEVISUALSTYLE,
            10, 10, 400, 20,
            hWnd,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            0);
        break;
    case WM_NOTIFY: {
        // 
        NMHDR *nmh = (NMHDR*)lParam;
        switch (nmh->code) {
        case NM_CLICK:
            if (nmh->hwndFrom == link) {
                NMLINK* lnkHdr = (NMLINK*)lParam;
                MessageBox(NULL, lnkHdr->item.szUrl, L"Here we open", MB_OK);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

In action, it looks like this:

[image]

When clicked, it pops up a message box like this:

[image]

The exact look you get for the window frames and such will depend a bit on how you build it, the OS Version you run it on, and so on. You indicated an interest in Windows XP. I don't have a copy of that handy to test on any more, but I ran this on the oldest I still have around (Windows 7).

Comment: Firstly I added the pragma, the link was still in plain text. Then I checked `InitCommonControlsEx()`'s return, no problem. Then I moved the `CreateWindowEx()` from `InitInstance()` to `WndProc()`, it's not plaintext anymore, now it's a hyperlink. Thank you very much, I think you are great